# Remove indentation of xml files

Tags: java, regex, removing-whitespace

I am writing a function that I will use for my unit tests. I want to compare XML files, but as one of them will be created by a Third party library I want to mitigate any possible differences because of different indentation. Thus I wrote the following function:

```
private String normalizeXML(String xmlString) {
    String res = xmlString.replaceAll("[ \t]+", " ");
    // leading whitespaces are inconsistent in the resulting xmls.
    res = res.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
    return res.trim();
}
```

However this function is not removing the leading interval on each line of the XML.

When I write the function in this way (difference in the first regex):

```
private String normalizeXMLs(String xmlString) {
    String res = xmlString.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
    // leading whitespaces are inconsistent in the resulting xmls.
    res = res.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
    return res.trim();
}
```

It does remove the trailing white space, but it also makes the xml appear as a single line which is very troubling when you need to compare the differences.

I just can not justify why the first implementation does not displace the leading interval. Any ideas?

**EDIT**: Even more interesting is that if I make a single line manipulation:

```
String res = xmlString.replaceAll("^\\s+", "");
```

This line does not remove any of identation!

Comment: one problem with this approach is that it might remove whitespace that is actually significant.  Newlines and spaces that could appear as the value inside the tag's text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than trying to manipulate the string representations, it would be safer to use a dedicated XML comparison tool such as [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/) that allows you to define exactly which differences are significant and which aren't.  Trying to modify XML data using regular expressions is rarely a good idea, you should use a proper XML parser that knows all the rules of what makes well formed XML.

Comment: Thank you for the very reasonable comment and pointing me to this library. Still, I thought I understand regexes. I can not just let it be with this unexplainable behavoir.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev In Java regular expressions `^` only matches the very beginning of the input by default.  If you want it to anchor after embedded newlines within the string as well, then you need to enable the "multiline" flag: `replaceAll("(?m)^\\s+", "")`

Comment: Now, this is an answer that was very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
String res = xmlString.replaceAll("[ \\t]+", " ");
```

Not \t...

Comment: Nope, I actually feel the second regex miraculously stops working with the first regex.

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me:

```
    private static String normalizeXMLs(String xmlString) {
    String res = xmlString.replaceAll("\\t", "");
    return res.trim();
}
```

Good luck :)